# Denodo throwing error "The field properties can only be specified for derived fields" on a job while altering column description of columns

Tags: denodo

I have created a job in denodo to update column descriptions of all the views.
All the information related to views are stored in glossary only.We have created a view on top of this glossary datasource.We are then creating a view which contains a column having the script(alter statement to alter column desc). This column is fetched in our job.
When we are executing this job(selecting this column only), it should execute the alter statement.
Unfortunately job is getting failed with felow error:
"The field properties can only be specified for derived fields"

I want the job to execute and need to update column description

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that you're trying to update column descriptions of all views using a job in Denodo by executing a column that contains an alter script. However, the job fails with the error message "The field properties can only be specified for derived fields."

This error suggests an attempt to modify properties of a field that's not derived in the view.

Try this VQL line to solve your problem:

```
ALTER VIEW view_name (ALTER COLUMN column_name ADD ( DESCRIPTION = 'test'))
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is the alter statement which i have used previously.
But the job fails with the error message "The field properties can only be specified for derived fields."
Please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).